# Question about this object literal

Tags: javascript

What happens when returnThis.label is referenced? 
Can one give me an example of how this might be used?

```
returnThis = {
        'label' : aLabel ? this.value : false
        };
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This makes use of ternary syntax.

`aLabel ? this.value : false` means: if `aLabel` is truthy (true, 1, "a", etc.), evaluate to `this.value`. Otherwise, evaulate to `false`.

The code is equivalent to the following:

```
returnThis = {};
if(aLabel) {
    returnThis.label = this.value;
} else {
    returnThis.label = false;
}
```

Comment: sorry. The usage of var newVAr=returnThis.label, will result in newVar having this.value if returnThis.label happens to be true?

Answer (score 3):

Nothing happens (it just gets the value). The statement: `aLabel ? this.value : false` has already been executed.